# choosing RTOS, CPU and IDE to help with splitting .NET app in two: embedded(firmware) app and windows(.NET) app

Tags: .net, exception, ide, rtos

choosing RTOS, CPU and IDE to help with splitting .NET app in two: embedded(firmware) app and windows(.NET) app

Comment: If that device is essentially going to be a slave to the .net app, why do you need all that relatively high end stuff like usb, tcp/ip and filesystems?  IMO you may want to rethink the partitioning of your application between the embedded device and the .net app...

Comment: It is not just a slave app.its responsibilites will only grow over time.

Comment: The last decade has not been kind to RTOSes.  The raw horse power in commodity hardware put them in the niche zone.  If a .NET solution is already in place and working for you then there's little need to consider something as drastic as an RTOS.  For one, they are not going to boot .NET, the garbage collector is not exactly compatible with RT.  True cost is in the number of hours you burn on rewriting and interfacing all this.

Comment: thanks for the advise, but can anyone answer the question without posting the concerns?

Comment: On top, as it is obvious you dont need RTOS, why go for one now? because it is a buzzword you dont understand? It iy obvious a normal OS works well enough (as you do so with the .NET app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTOS, TCP/IP, Filesystem, and USB need not be tightly integrated (i.e. you do not necessarily need an RTOS that includes all those already), it is entirely possible, and in fact not too difficult to obtain all those components independently and integrate them yourself.  That would give you the widest choice of solution.  For example, I have successfully integrated Keil's RTX kernel (free with their ARM toochain) with [ELM FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html), and STMicroelectronics' STM32 USB library.  That said, Keil also provide an extended (non free) library that includes TCP/IP, USB, and filesystem that would be easier to integrate.

However there are many possible integrated solutions, as a one-stop shop, Segger provide separate RTOS, TCP/IP, USB and file-system libraries that can be easily integrated.  f cost is an issue eCos os an open source OS with all those things includes and a large ecosystem of contributed code and libraries.

For tight coupling with .NET on the PC you might do better using .NETmicro on the embedded system, but that is not real-time capable and requires  about 300Kb jut to boot as opposed to perhaps 30Kb for an RTOS with USB, TCP/IP and a filesystem.

You mention CPU choice in the title, but not in the question.  You need to consider performance requirements and I/O capability.  Obviously if it supports Ethernet and USB on-chip that would be a good start.  Many microcontrollers have these peripherals, but the widest choice of vendors for a single architecture can be found in ARM based devices.  I suggest that you look at STM32 or Freescale Kinetis devices, being ARM Cortex M3/4 devices with a wide selection of on-chip peripheral combinations and development boards.

Comment: Thank you Clifford!  I like the idea of adding communication libraries as needed.What made you choose RTX? Is it flexible to different IDEs?

Comment: RTX because it was free with the toolchain!  In fact it is fairly limited, and has caused a few problems, I am not sure whether due to bugs, or design limitations, but porting the application to Segger embOS took only about a week and it has proven far more reliable far more quickly.  The application code was already written to an abstraction layer (as a C++ class library) over the RTOS so did not have to change.  The RTOS aware debugging for RTX is limited and not as useful as it may seem, embOS has embOSView, and if you use IAR's toolchain, it has RTOS aware debugging for embOS in any case.

Comment: @Clifford Can you elaborate on why you choose to move to embOS?

Comment: @Vincent: Prior experience with the product.  FreeRTOS was also considered, but context switch times were considerably slower (thouugh still <20us on Cortex-M3 @72MHz).  Also I had implemented a C++ RTOS abstraction layer so that the RTOS could be changed without application changes and embOS was a good fit for the abstraction layer (i.e. the layer was mostly a thin wrapper because the underlying C API included most of the mechanisms provided by the class interface).

Comment: @Clifford Which one would you recommend between RTX and embOS? I'm planning to use all the middle-ware components (GUI, USB D/H, TCP/IP, FS) and also add, like you did, an abstraction layer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well if you are going to be using Keil ARM-MDK Standard or Pro, RTX, GUI, USB, FS, and TCP/IP support is included - the GUI support incidentally is in fact Segger's emWin.  So RTX may be the path of least resistance and at no additional cost. My was originally designed for VxWorks, ported to embOS, then to RTX, and embOS is just a closer fit to the original design.  RTX does not like OS objects to be initialised before the kernel is initialised, making the use of static objects from the C++ abstraction layer problematic since they can be instantiated before main().

Answer (score 0):

Too many variables in equation... I suppose you should choose CPU first (according to your technical requirements and perspective) and then consult with manufacturer/community on which ecosystem is available for this core (compiler, tools, RTOS, debugger, IDE, simulator, demo-boards, starter-kits, etc)